# How to resolve relationship using Composer Query?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

My assets:
Vehicle which contains an owner.

I want to list all vehicles along with its owner information using Query in queries.qry.
Using AssetRegistry I can get the results using resolveAll method, anyway how to get the same result using Query?

Answer (score 1):

`resolveAll` isn't available in the Composer runtime at the time of writing (ie like it is in composer-client) so you can't get all resolved relationships invoking a Query (say in a TP) - see Issue 
 https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3454 . But you can get them via REST Filters ; adding `{"include":"resolve"}` as a filter, will resolve all the relationships to the asset owners and you can process the results that way.

Comment: Because I don’t want to use RESTful API yet, I still doubt about Multi user mode on REStful API. Do you have any idea how to expose API in a secure way?

Comment: For REST APIs https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/securing-the-rest-server and one example of an authentication strategy (there are 300+ which can be used with the REST server)  is this tutorial https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest  - for normal JS client APIs again TLS / HTTPS is a must anyway - you would implement security like you would any other client APIs. Using API keys is one way - discussed here http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/09/12/securing-api-keys-in-a-client-side-javascript-app/ , once the app user has authenticated.